# Postscript test condition

Tags: postscript

I have a snippet a code which says:

```
input encrypt test
```

where input is a string, encrypt is (I assume) a function and test is (I assume again) a string. I'm completely new to postscript but would the syntax above be equivalent to:

```
if encrypt(input) == test:
    return True
```

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough here to go on, we'd need to see considerably more of the program to be able to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes it is. Found out by debugging but maybe useful for someone else.

Edit for clarification: in my case `encrypt` is indeed a function that takes a string as input and defines a string. `test` takes a string as input and returns a boolean hence why it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of `input`,  `encrypt`, nor `test` are PostScript built-in commands, one can't say for sure what they do.  Given the way that the language works, and your assertion that `input` is a string, some possibilities for a Python-like equivalent are:

```
test(encrypt(input))  % test and encrypt are functions of one argument

test(encrypt, input)  % encrypt is a function with no arguments

encrypt(input); test()  % encrypt returns nothing

encrypt(); test(input)  % encrypt() takes no arguments, returns no values

encrypt(input); next_fn(test)

etc.
```

But I don't see how it can be:

```
if encrypt(input) == test:
```

given PostScript's stack-based syntax unless there's more to the sequence:

```
input encrypt test eq
```

Then it could evaluate as:

```
eq(test, encrypt(input))
```

which *would* match your conclusion.  But since `eq` is not part of your sequence, and non of the listed commands are PostScript built-ins, It's not clear how your question and answer might be useful to others.